# Is my eid-ul-adha sacrifice valid if I get it done through a charity organization?

Tags: sacrifice, reward, eid-ul-adha

There are many charitable organisations which offer donators the opportunity to perform Eid sacrifice through or on behalf of them.

Such charities are Human Appeal, now I understand that rules apply when it comes to Eid sacrifice such as the distribution of meat and watching your sacrifice being slaughtered, would I get a reward and an accepted sacrifice if I perform this through a charity?

Within my country there is no butchers available to slaughter animals and I have not got a family where the meat is to be distributed.

Comment: Did you pay for the animal?

Comment: @Sayyid , Yes i did and they let you choose the animal and country, and they don't send any videos confirming the slaughter but they are a very trustable orgnisation, Allah knows best..(3eed Mubarak Brother)

Comment: If you paid for the animal and intended to sacrifice for Allah, then there shouldn't be any problem.  Even if they didn't do it, your intention is known to Allah,

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there mustn't be any problem if you do it by a valuable and Islamic organizations. So, as a rule (of Allah) your act will be accepted if you do it with a good intention and also if you searched to find a valuable Islamic organization (even though they do not do it ...)

But the significant point is that you should search regarding the organization which you want to pay your money to, whenever you became sure, then pay money to them. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to do it yourself as far as Sunnah is concerned, but if the situation is such that you can't do it by yourself or even can't touch the blade while the cattle is being slaughtered by a professional or live in a full concrete place where disposing blood is difficult then there is no harm in doing so (I mean sacrifice by charitable org or such).